# Best Approach to overcome stack size limitation for ZK-Proof verification

Tags: runtime, sealevel

I'm working on designing ZK-STARK rollups for Solana - by deploying a general purpose stark verifier on solana. A typical proof is around ~50KB. What would be the most efficient approach to write the proof on-chain so that it can be used by an on-chain verifier to check the execution of a given program hash? Should I just use multiple transactions to write it to storage, and then stream the data in 4KB chunks for verification, or is there any better approach? Any resources would also be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the approach mostly correct.

- You'll have to write the proof into an account over multiple transactions, pretty much exactly how the BPF loader processes the "write" instruction into program accounts. Here's the start of the processor code to write bytes at a certain offset: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/bd9b311c630a10bb5c16b567e51bd61c21aabff9/programs/bpf_loader/src/lib.rs#L489
- After that, depending on how you process things, you may be able to get around the 4kb stack size limit, since the proof is written into an account, which is available as a reference to its bytes. If you transmute the bytes into a reference to your proof type using something like `bytemuck`, you should be able to avoid allocating anything on the stack. For example:

```
use bytemuck::{Pod, Zeroable};

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Pod, Zeroable)]
#[repr(C)]
struct TestStruct {
    big_number: u64,
    small_number: u32,
    padding: u32,
}
fn main() {
    let data = [1u8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    let my_test: &TestStruct = bytemuck::try_from_bytes(&data).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(my_test.big_number, 1);
    assert_eq!(my_test.small_number, 2);
}
```